# pandas.read_csv not partitioning data at semicolon delimiter

Tags: python, file, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a tough time correctly loading `csv` file to pandas dataframe. The file is `csv` saved in MS Excel, where the rows looks like this:

```
Montservis, s.r.o.;"2 012";"-14.98";"-34.68";"- 11.7";"0.02";"0.09";"0.16";"284.88";"10.32";"
```

I am using

```
filep="file_name.csv"
raw_data = pd.read_csv(filep,engine="python",index_col=False, header=None, delimiter=";")
```

(I have tried several combinations and alternatives of read_csv arguments, but without any success.....I have tried also read_table )

What I want to see in my dataframe that each semi colon separated value will be in separate column (I understand that `read_csv` works this way(?)).

Unfortunately, I always end up with whole row being placed in first column of dataframe. So basicly after loading I have many rows, but only one column (two if I count also indexes)

I have placed sample here: 
[datafile](https://files.mycloud.com/home.php?brand=webfiles&seuuid=8fcff2efbe72afb369bb4fffbaaf9fe9&name=example)

Any idea welcomed.

Comment: Can you not just export the file out as a normal csv? i.e. without quotes and with commas? currently you have semi-colons inside quotes and it's difficult to know how to correctly delimit your columns

Comment: I have tried also without quotes (just did replace " by  space in excel) , but didnt help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add  `quoting  = 3`. 3 is for `QUOTE_NONE` refer [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
   raw_data = pd.read_csv(filep,engine="python",index_col=False, header=None, delimiter=";", quoting = 3)
```

This will give `[7 rows x 23 columns]` dataframe

Comment: Perfect, thank you. That solved it. However resulting output is not very nice, the data in cells are in double quotes e.g. ""2 012"". I can live/take care of that so this is not huge issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is enclosing characters which can be ignored by `\` character.

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv(filep,engine="python",index_col=False, header=None, delimiter='\;')
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer, same as @Marlon Abeykoon's works!

Comment: Thank you, this found to me